# Select random item from Javascript record array and convert it to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I randomly select an item from the following Javascript record array, and then take the result and convert it into an array and then select a random item from it?

```
plot = [
        {
            postcode: "MK1",
            area: "Denbigh, Mount Farm",
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK2",
            area: "Brickfields, Central Bletchley, Fenny Stratford, Water Eaton"
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK3",
            area: "Church Green, Far Bletchley, Old Bletchley, West Bletchley",
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK4",
            area: "Emerson Valley, Furzton, Kingsmead, Shenley Brook End, Snelshall West, Tattenhoe, Tattenhoe Park, Westcroft, Whaddon, Woodhill",
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK5",
            area: "Crownhill, Elfield Park, Grange Farm, Oakhill, Knowlhill, Loughton, Medbourne, Shenley Brook End, Shenley Church End, Shenley Lodge, Shenley Wood",
        }
    ]
```

For example, if the second item is selected, then from the area field, I want to select one of either `"Brickfields, Central Bletchley, Fenny Stratford, Water Eaton"` and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Look into `Math.random()` and `split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function to get random integers where min, max are inclusive**

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

**Function to find Random Value from passed variable `plot`**

```
function getRandomValue(plot)
{
var rN1 = getRandomInt(0,plot.length-1);
var areaArray= plot[rN1].area.split(",");
var rN2 = getRandomInt(0,areaArray.length-1);
return areaArray[rN2];
}
```

**And use it like**

```
plot = [
        {
            postcode: "MK1",
            area: "Denbigh, Mount Farm",
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK2",
            area: "Brickfields, Central Bletchley, Fenny Stratford, Water Eaton"
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK3",
            area: "Church Green, Far Bletchley, Old Bletchley, West Bletchley",
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK4",
            area: "Emerson Valley, Furzton, Kingsmead, Shenley Brook End, Snelshall West, Tattenhoe, Tattenhoe Park, Westcroft, Whaddon, Woodhill",
        },
        {
            postcode: "MK5",
            area: "Crownhill, Elfield Park, Grange Farm, Oakhill, Knowlhill, Loughton, Medbourne, Shenley Brook End, Shenley Church End, Shenley Lodge, Shenley Wood",
        }
    ]

console.log(getRandomValue(plot))
```